# How to Customising the WiX Burn theme with additional input button and open other page on click?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.10

I am creating a wix bootstrapper project which executes 2 msi files sequencially. I want user to have UI which enables user to select msi files to be executed(some what similar to feature selection UI), for that i have added a button on Install Page

```
<Page Name="Install">
<Richedit Name="EulaRichedit" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="-70" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HexStyle="0x800000" />
<Checkbox Name="EulaAcceptCheckbox" X="-11" Y="-41" Width="260" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallAcceptCheckbox)</Checkbox>
<Button Name="OptionsButton" X="-171" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallOptionsButton)</Button>
<Button Name="FeatureButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">Feature</Button>

<Button Name="InstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
<Button Name="WelcomeCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallCloseButton)</Button>
</Page>
```

Now I want when i click `FeatureButton` a new page must appear.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the default Bootstrapper you will need to create your own custom Bootstrapper.

Have a look at this link to get you started:

https://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/